# Firebase $onAuth has wrong authData after $authWithOAuthRedirect from Facebook

Tags: angularjs, facebook, oauth, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to authenticate users of my Firebase (Angularfire) app with Facebook Login.

Everything works as expected when I authenticate with a pop-up window, but to support as many browsers as possible (Chrome on iOS doesn't support pop-ups, for e.g.) I want to fallback to authenticating with a redirect (`$authWithOAuthRedirect`).

I have confirmed my setting in Facebook are correct (my app ID and secret, for e.g.) but when I am redirected back to my app after Facebook authenticating with a redirect, `$onAuth` fires but I don't have my Facebook `authData`.

Instead, I have anonymous `authData`. For a bit of background; all users are authenticated anonymously if they are not otherwise authenticated (with Facebook, in this e.g.).

I can't see to find why this would be - the user should now be authenticated with Facebook, and have the Facebook `authData`.

Excepts of my code are below for some context:

**Triggered when a user clicks the login button**

```
function logIn () {
    firebaseAuth
        .$authWithOAuthRedirect('facebook', function (error) {
            if (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });
}
```

**`$onAuth` (inside my Angular app's `run`)**

```
function run ($rootScope, firebaseAuth, sessionStore) {
    $rootScope
        .$on('$routeChangeError', function (event, next, prev, error) {
            if (error === 'AUTH_REQUIRED') {
                console.log(error);
            }
        });

    $rootScope
        .$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (event, current, prev) {
            $rootScope.title = current.$$route.title;
        });

    firebaseAuth
        .$onAuth(onAuth);

    function onAuth (authData) {
        console.log(authData);
    }
}
```

Route resolver to otherwise anonymously authenticates users

```
function sessionState ($q, firebaseAuth) {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

    firebaseAuth
        .$requireAuth()
        .then(deferred.resolve, guest);

    return deferred.promise;

    function guest () {
        firebaseAuth
            .$authAnonymously()
            .then(deferred.resolve, rejected);
    }

    function rejected () {
        deferred.reject('AUTH_REQUIRED');
    }
}
```

The route resolver (`sessionState`) checks to see if the user is authenticated already, and if not, tries to anonymously authenticate them.

After the Facebook authentication redirect, the user will already be authenticated, and therefore does not need to be anonymously authenticated.

But, it appears that they are? As `$onAuth` logs the `authData` to the console, and it is anonymous.

Any help with this would be much appreciated! I am sure it has something to do with my route resolver, as pop-up authentication works fine (the route is already resolved).

**EDIT:** I tried completely removing my route resolver in case it was that causing an issue, but it made no difference. The user was just 'unauthenticated' instead of being either authenticated with Facebook (after `$authWithOAuthRedirect`) or anonymously.

**UPDATE:** I tried authenticating with Twitter and the redirect transport and I have encountered the exact same problem. I have also tried using port 80, instead of port 3000 that my app was being served on locally, but no joy.

**UPDATE:** When I turn off `html5Mode` mode in my app - and routes now begin with `#`s - `$authWithOAuthRedirect` works perfectly. From this I can only assume that `$authWithOAuthRedirect` does not support AngularJS's `html5Mode`. Can anyone confirm this is an issue, or do I need to change my code to support `html5Mode` and `authWithOAuthRedirect`?

**EXAMPLE REPO** Here is an example repo demonstrating the problem: https://github.com/jonathonoates/myapp

Look in the `dist` directory - you should be able to download this and run the app to reproduce the problem. In `scripts/main.js` is the app's JS; I've added a couple of comments but it's pretty self explanatory.

To reproduce the problem: click on the 'Facebook Login' button, and you'll be redirected to Facebook to authenticate. FB will redirect you back to the app, but here lies the problem - you won't be authenticated, and the returned authData will be null - you'll see this in the console

**UPDATE:** When I add a `hashPrefix` in `html5Mode` e.g.

```
$locationProvider
    .html5Mode(true)
    .hashPrefix('!');
```

The app works as I would expect - authenticating with Facebook and the redirect transport works.

Couple of niggles though:

1. The URL has `#%3F` appended to it, and is available/visible in the browser's history.
2. This would rewrite URLs with `#!` in browsers that do not support `History.pushState` (`html5Mode`), and some less advanced search engines might look for a HTML fragment because of the 'hashbang'.

I'll look into highjacking the URL upon being redirected back from Facebook instead of using `hashPrefix`. In the URL there is a `__firebase_request_key` which may be significant e.g.

```
http://localhost:3000/#%3F&__firebase_request_key=
```

Comment: Jonathon, could you try downloading 2.4.0? A fix for URLs with hashes went out in that release and I suspect it will help.

Comment: Then instead of code excerpts, we'll need a minimal repro. See [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Here is a MCVE for you to look at - in this I have verified that the Facebook redirect transport does not work with `html5mode` turned on. I'll also update my Q with the link: https://github.com/jonathonoates/myapp

Comment: That's a repo. What are the steps to run this? Do I look in dist/ or app/? At what? Not trying to be annoying, but you need to provide enough data to verify and reproduce the issue before I'm going to commit resources to helping.

Comment: Thanks for your patience; I've just updated the `dist`directory with an un-minifed, complete example with a few comments for clarity. You should be able to just pull down the `dist` directory and run the app to reproduce the problem. Just click on the 'Facebook Login' button, and you'll be redirected to Facebook to authenticate. FB will redirect you back to the app, but here lies the problem. You won't be authenticated, and the returned `authData` will be `null` - you'll see this in the console. Thanks for you help

Comment: @JonathonOates As a workaround, I append `?!` to the end of the URI, and it works in my app. For example:  `www.myapp.com/#/login?!`   in which case I don't use html5 mode.

Comment: @rattanak thanks, but if I turn off `html5mode` there isn't an issue away. This whole problem only arises when `html5mode` is turned on.

Comment: @JonathonOates I see what you mean. In my app, after authenticating, `?__firebase_request_key=somekey` was added to the url. It did not go away as in your app. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @rattanak no idea. It seems that if the redirect transport takes the user back to the root URL of the app (e.g. `www.myapp.com`) then `__firebase_request_key` is appended, but no authentication actually takes place (`$onAuth`) is not fired. Any other URL, or route and authentication takes place. Which is why my workaround (and yours) works. This definitely looks like bug - hopefully @Kato and the Firebase team can help.

Comment: In my app, when the user click login, they are not on the root URL. they are on myapp.com/path/anotherPath. After the redirect transport returns to the URL, `$onAuth` still fires but `_firebase_request_key` does not go away. @JonathonOates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like this is indeed an incompatibility between Firebase and AngularJS's html5mode as you suspected.  At the end of the redirect flow, Firebase was leaving the URL as "http://.../#?", and Angular apparently doesn't like that so it did a redirect to "http://.../"  This redirect interrupts Firebase (the page reloads while we're trying to auth against the backend) and so it is unable to complete the authentication process.

I've made an experimental fix that ensures we revert the URL to http://.../#" at the end of the redirect flow, which Angular is happy with, thus preventing the problematic redirect.  You can grab it here if you like: https://mike-shared.firebaseapp.com/firebase.js

I'll make sure this fix gets into the next version of the JS client.  You can keep an eye on our [changelog](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/changelog.html) to see when it is released.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - it's taken a lot of trial and error to get here, but I'm glad we're getting nearer a solution. One thing to note; I'm not using AngularJS 2 - I'm using 1.4.4 in my app and repro. Do you think this is one of the same problem?

Comment: Oh, sorry. That was just me getting confused. I thought you mentioned Angular 2 in your question, but I see I am mistaken. :-)  I'll edit my answer.  I debugged the issue using your repro app, so it's definitely the same. :-)

Comment: Great, I'll look out for the next version of Firebase. Hopefully it won't be too far away! Quite chuffed I found a bug ;-)